# Confusion in MLE for continuous distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function, maximum-likelihood

Suppose I have a Bernoulli distribution. It is discrete, so the semantics of derivation of MLE as a joint *pmf* is clear. For sample set $X_1, X_2,\cdots,X_m$,

$$
L(p) = P(X_1=x_1;X_2=x_2;\cdots;X_n=x_m) = \prod_{i=1}^mP(X_i=x_i) 
= \prod_{i=1}^mp^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i} \tag{1}
$$

And then we derive $L_{max}(P) = \hat{p} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^mx_i}{m}$. So far so good.

We actually started with finding out the joint probability mass function of all our sample data occurrences. Since each occurrence is independent, we simply multiplied individual *pmf*.

I am unable to take this same notion to *pdf*. For eg, normal distribution. Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_m$ bea random sample from a normal distribution $N(\theta_1, \theta_2)$.

Then,

$$
L(\theta_1,\theta_2) = P(X_1=x_1;X_2=x_2;\cdots;X_n=x_m) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_i-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}  \Big]} \tag{2}
$$

**Question 1:**
It is here I am stuck. The individual probabilities of $P(X_i=x_i)$ are $0$ for continuous *pdf* without a continuity correction. So how do we justify doing above step? What is the notion I am missing here?

**My take:** 
Here is my take so far but I doubt if its correct. Unlike a *pmf* which directly gives $P(X_i=x_i)$, a *pdf* only a function and always needs integration to find the probability area. That is,

If $x_1$  is a sample observation from $N(\theta_1, \theta_2)$, then of course $P(X_1=x_1)=0$, and we are not interested in that in particular (which was a wrong notion implicitly implanted while attempting joint *pmf*). Instead we are interested in a collective probability density *function* of all samples' individual probability densities.

That is,  below is a *continuous* pdf for sample $X_1$

$$
A = f(x_1; \theta_1, \theta_2) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_1-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}}\Big]  \tag{3}
$$

But when we want to find a probability with above *pdf* its always in a range. For example,

$$
P(X_1 \leq a) = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x_1; \theta_1, \theta_2)dx_1 \tag{4}
$$

Similarly, for another sample $X_2$ from same *pdf*,

$$
B = f(x_2; \theta_1, \theta_2) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_2-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}}\Big] \tag{5}
$$

And for that, for an interesting range, the probability could be something like below.

$$
P(X_2 \leq b) = \int_{-\infty}^{b} f(x_2; \theta_1, \theta_2)dx_2 \tag{6}
$$

Note A and B are the *functions* while, eq. $4$ and $6$ denote a probability calculated out of those functions. When we say, we are interested in *joint pdf*, we are interested in the multiplication of the *functions* A and B (because they are independent), and not probabilities like $4$ and $6$. The probability of any joint interested event could be calculated in resultant function AB. That is,

$$
AB = f(x_1,x_2;\theta_1,\theta_2) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{2} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_i-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}}\Big] \tag{7}
$$

And then, in this *joint pdf* I could calculate interested probabilities, for example,

$$
P(X_1 \leq a; X_2 \leq b) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_1=a}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2=b} \prod\limits_{i=1}^{2} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_i-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}}\Big] \tag{8}
$$

Generalizing,

$$
P(X_1 \leq x_1; X_2 \leq x_2) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{2} \int_{-\infty}^{x_i} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_i-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}}\Big] \tag{9}
$$

Not just left area, but any probability of interest could be calculated after this step. For example,

$$
P(X_1 \geq x_1; X_2 \geq x_2) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{2} \int_{x_i}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_i-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}}\Big] \tag{10}
$$

This is why, unlike *pmf*, for a pdf,

$$
f(x_1,x_2;\theta_1,\theta_2) = f(x_1;\theta_1,\theta_2)f(x_2;\theta_1,\theta_2) \\ 
\neq P(X_1 \leq x_1; X_2 \leq x_2) \\
\neq P(X_1 \geq x_1; X_2 \geq x_2) \\
\neq P(X_1 = x_1; X_2 = x_2)
$$

**Question 2:** 
Can you please confirm if this understanding is correct and why if not so, and what am I still missing?

**Note:**

1. I am aware of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154046/what-does-it-mean-to-do-mle-with-a-continuous-variable) which discusses similar issue, but I could not yet find convincing answer there, so I am asking again here in a way I understood the problem and to add my understanding. I also could not find any convincing answer anywhere else. :(

Comment: The likelihood function is often taken to be the joint distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ . So joint pmf and joint pdf are both valid, depending on whether the $X_i$'s have discrete or absolutely continuous distributions.

Comment: As for the pdf you mention, if it is the normal distribution you are referring to, then the pdf is not correct.

Comment: Hi, am no statistician (and have always found MLE a bit odd), but heuristically, if the the joint density is smooth enough, one could reasonably state that for a given $\epsilon$, the finite probability in an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood  of the (global) maximum $\mathbf{x_0}$ say is maximised over all such neighbourhoods. At least that's how I've intuitively, hand-wavily understood it without bothering to prove the details... Perhaps someone can give you a rigorous answer!

Comment: @StubbornAtom which pdf or step is not correct? can you please point to eq. number?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I just fixed a careless mistake, are the equations ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is here I am stuck. The individual probabilities of P(Xi=xi) are 0 for continuous pdf without a continuity correction. So how do we justify doing above step? What is the notion I am missing here?

You need to use probability density instead of probabilities. Definition of [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function):

*The likelihood function is always defined as a function of the parameter ${\displaystyle \theta }$  equal to (or sometimes proportional to) the density of the observed data with respect to a common or reference measure, for both discrete and continuous probability distributions.* So, your step is completely justified.

True that the individual probabilities are zero and to get probabilities from pdfs you need to integrate over some interval.  Have a [look at this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107563/do-the-pdf-and-the-pmf-and-the-cdf-contain-the-same-information) on CV.

$L(\theta_1,\theta_2) = p(X_1=x_1;X_2=x_2;\cdots;X_m=x_m|\theta_1,\theta_2) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}{\text{exp}}{\Big[ -\dfrac{  (x_i-\theta_1)^2 }{2\theta_2}  \Big]} \tag{1}$

where $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are mean and variance respectively.

And $p(X_1=x_1;X_2=x_2;\cdots;X_m=x_m)$ is the joint density.

And, the likelihood will be:

$L(\theta_1,\theta_2) = p(X_1=x_1;X_2=x_2;\cdots;X_m=x_m|\theta_1,\theta_2) =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi\theta_2)^m}}{\text{exp}}{-\frac{1}{2\theta_2}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_i-\theta_1)^2 }} \tag{2}$

To get the values of $\theta_1,\theta_2$, maximize the likelihood by taking derivatives w.r.t the desired variable.

> Instead we are interested in a collective probability density function of all samples' individual probability densities.

I doubt this statement. You are interested in pdf of the sample from a normal population. But, you are missing that sample points are realizations of a distribution. *They are not random variables but rather a realization of random variables.*

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)):

A sample concretely represents the results of n experiments in which the same quantity is measured. For example, if we want to estimate the average height of members of a particular population, we measure the heights of n individuals. Each measurement is drawn from the probability distribution F characterizing the population, so each measured height ${\displaystyle x_{i}} $ is the realization of a random variable ${\displaystyle X_{i}}$ with distribution F. Note that a set of random variables (i.e., a set of measurable functions) must not be confused with the realizations of these variables (which are the values that these random variables take). In other words, ${\displaystyle X_{i}}$ is a function representing the measurement at the i-th experiment and ${\displaystyle x_{i}=X_{i}(\omega )}$ is the value obtained when making the measurement.

Comment: If individual probabilities are 0, how is it ok to write $L(\theta_1,\theta_2) = P(X_1=x_1;X_2=x_2;\cdots;X_m=x_m)$, shouldn't there an alternate notation for pdf? It is not making sense to say  $P(X_1=x_1) = 0$ for pdf, and then write as (1) above?!

Comment: Apologies for the notation. What I really meant was joint density. Have edited the answer.

Comment: No apologies please, I highly appreciate people here taking time to clarify :)  By the way, what I meant was, and also my understanding, that for pdf, we should not have probability notation at all $P(X_1=x_i;..)$ because it is not joint "probability", the probability is realized only after an integration later. So will it be better to stop at $f(x_1, x_2,..x_m | \theta_1,\theta_2)$ and proceed to multiplying individual pdfs? And my "take" I explained in my question was correct?

Comment: I agree with you on the notation part. That is why I have use $'p'$ instead of$'P'$ to denote joint density. And this is a practice followed widely. Yes, sure the multiplication is of individual densities only.

Comment: oh ok, I did not know that, As per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_in_probability_and_statistics), $f(x)$ or $f_X(x)$ is used.

Comment: Only if you had a look at the last example in this link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: That last section gives rises to new set of questions. If as said there, $f_Z(z) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f_X \left( x \right) f_Y \left( z/x \right) \frac{1}{|x|}\, dx$, for just Z=XY (two random variable scenario) then our simple multiplication of pdfs are wrong? If not, why?

Comment: What you have multiplied are not pdfs of random variables, rather the probability density values of sample $x_i$, sampled from the same distribution.

Comment: 1) Suppose I have $X(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, and $Y(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, that is both having similar distribution of same parameters $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$. For Z = XX (that is our case), $f(x_1,x_2;\theta_1,\theta_2) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} f_X(x_1)f_X(x_2)$. but for Z=XY, $f(x_1,y_1;\theta_1,\theta_2) = f_X(x_1)f_Y(y_1|x_1)\frac{1}{|x_1|}$?
2) I wonder why each $X_i$ cannot be considered as a random variable with $N(\theta_1, \theta_2)$. **Similar** and **same** are confusing. It is not that, there exists a physical distribution can, from which we pick up samples.

Comment: If the parameters are the same and distribution is normal then $X(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and $Y(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ are the same random variable. So, IMHO Z= XX = XY. The samples are the realized values that the random variable takes.

Comment: After you have got the samples, they are already determined, isn't it? Is there any randomness about them?

Comment: I meant samples could each individually be RV, because we generalize them while finding the joint pdf. What we try to find in MLE is what is the probability that I got all these sample values. What I get confused now is, in wiki link of product dist, they say X and Y are independent and **identical**, so that extra conditional density and diving by absolute $|x|$ is confusing me, why they are there.

Comment: probably i should create a separate question and we should discuss or should take it to chat? others may feel we are deviating at this point.

Comment: You might want to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: done, i will create another question for getting confused about general product of distributions

Comment: I have created a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960890/confusion-in-product-of-pdfs-for-mle)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84640/discussion-between-paari-vendhan-and-naive).